# django mail webform not connection to mail server

Tags: django, email, smtp, zoho

I spent a lot of time developing the form and connecting all the pieces together and now I cannot connect to my smtp server through django settings. Here are my settings...

```
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'auto@domain.com'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.mailhost.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'auto@domain.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True 
EMAIL_PORT = 465
```

I tried to send it through my form and it didn't work so I tried to send one through the shell..

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
send_mail('subject','message','auto@domain.com', ['me@domain.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

and I get this traceback...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 62, in send_mail
    return mail.send()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 286, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 92, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 50, in open
    self.connection = connection_class(self.host, self.port, **connection_params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 312, in connect
    (code, msg) = self.getreply()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 363, in getreply
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly
```

closed")
SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should recheck the data you use: login, password, etc.

If it doesn't help, try to use **port 587**.

SMTP uses this one. I hope it will help.

495 is now deprecated.

Comment: that worked, wow frustrating...Why would my host specifically state only port 465 and then have 587 work?

Comment: [SMTP ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol#Ports) 

495 is now deprecated.